# javafx: How to create a cellFactory that takes into account of two properties from an object?

Tags: java, javafx

I have a `ReadOnlyBooleanProperty` named `caution` for every `Trade` object that I created. Each `Trade` object populates a row in the table view `fxTransactionLog`. Now I want the table **cell** to keep flashing in green colour and the text becomes yellow color in the same volume cell when `caution` is `true`.

And now I am struggling to make the cell flash. The problem is I am requiring the volume property column to be editable and flash depending on another boolean-binding property.

Essentially, the cellFactory is looking at two different properties, which is what makes this problem very difficult. **Because I constantly have to look up the table row from the volume column to obtain the Trade object and then look up the corresponding boolean-binding caution property.** It seems like this approach is convoluted.

```
public class Trade{
       private DoubleProperty volume;
       private ReadOnlyBooleanWrapper caution;

       public Trade(double volume){
            this.volume = new SimpleDoubleProperty(volume);
            this.caution = new ReadOnlyBooleanWrapper();
            this.caution.bind(this.volume.greaterThan(0));
       }

}
```

This is the code I have , but it is giving me errors.

```
fvolume.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Trade,Double>("price"));
PseudoClass flashHighlight = PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("flash-highlight");
        volume.setCellFactory(


            tv -> {
                TableCell<Trade, Double> cell = new TableCell<>();
                Timeline flasher = new Timeline(

                        new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(0.5), e -> {
                            cell.pseudoClassStateChanged(flashHighlight, true);
                        }),

                        new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(1.0), e -> {
                            cell.pseudoClassStateChanged(flashHighlight, false);
                        })
                );
                flasher.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);

                ChangeListener<Boolean> cautionListener = (obs, cautionWasSet, cautionIsNowSet) -> {
                    if (cautionIsNowSet) {
                        flasher.play();
                    } else {
                        flasher.stop();
                        cell.pseudoClassStateChanged(flashHighlight, false);
                    }
                };

                cell.itemProperty().addListener((obs, oldItem, newItem) -> {
                    if (oldItem != null) {
                        oldItem.cautionProperty().removeListener(cautionListener); //<--- PROBLEM 1
                    }
                    if (newItem == null) {
                        flasher.stop();
                        cell.pseudoClassStateChanged(flashHighlight, false);
                    } else {
                        newItem.cautionProperty().addListener(cautionListener); //<-- PROBLEM 2
                        if (newItem.cautionProperty().get()) { //<-- PROBLEM 3
                            flasher.play();
                        } else {
                            flasher.stop();
                            cell.pseudoClassStateChanged(flashHighlight, false);
                        }
                    }
                });
                return cell ;
            }
        );
```

**UPDATE:** I highlighted where the code went wrong, please see `PROBLEM 1,2,3` above. There is an error: `the method cautionProperty() is undefined for the Type Double.`

I also tried adding `getTableRow().getItem()` to `oldItem.cautionProperty().removeListener(cautionListener); <--- PROBLEM 1`, which becomes `oldItem.getTableRow().getItem().cautionProperty().removeListener(cautionListener);`.

And I am still getting the same error: `the method cautionProperty() is undefined for the Type Double.`

**UPDATE2:** I also tried replacing `OldItem` and `newItem` with `cell` and cast it back to a `Trade` object but when I compiled, I got a NullPointerException in the following lines.

```
((Trade)cell.getTableRow().getItem()).cautionProperty().removeListener(cautionListener);


((Trade) cell.getTableRow().getItem()).cautionProperty().addListener(cautionListener);
```

Error log:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at application.Controller.lambda$19(Controller.java:378)
    at application.Controller$$Lambda$370/220504298.changed(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper$SingleChange.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:182)
```

**UPDATE 3:** I tried another way to tackle this problem. Yet I am still getting a similar error: `NullPointerException` in the the following line

```
 final BooleanExpression be = flashExtractor.apply((T) getTableRow().getItem());
```

**METHOD 2:**

```
public static class AnimatedTableCell<T> extends TableCell<T,Double>{
    private static final PseudoClass PS_Cell_Flash = PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("flash-cell-positive");

    private final Function<T,BooleanExpression> flashExtractor;
    private final ChangeListener<Boolean> flashListener = (fObs, fOld, fNew) -> flasherChanged(fNew);
    private final Timeline flashTimeline;

    // constructor
    public AnimatedTableCell(Function<T, BooleanExpression> fFlashExtractor){
        flashExtractor = fFlashExtractor;
        flashTimeline = new Timeline(
                new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(0.5), e -> pseudoClassStateChanged(PS_Cell_Flash, true)),
                new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(1.0), e -> pseudoClassStateChanged(PS_Cell_Flash, false)));
        flashTimeline.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);
    }

    private void flasherChanged(boolean fNew) {
        if (fNew) {
            flashTimeline.play();
        } else {
            flashTimeline.stop();
            pseudoClassStateChanged(PS_Cell_Flash, false);
        }
    }

    //@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    protected void updateItem(Double item, boolean empty) {
        System.out.println("getItem(): " + (T) getTableRow().getItem());
        if (getItem() != null) {
            // Problem IN THIS LINE
            final BooleanExpression be = flashExtractor.apply((T) getTableRow().getItem());
            if (be != null) {
                be.removeListener(flashListener);
            }
        }

        super.updateItem(item, empty);

        if (getItem() != null) {
            final BooleanExpression be = flashExtractor.apply((T) getTableRow().getItem());
            if (be != null) {
                be.addListener(flashListener);
                flasherChanged(be.get());
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Isnt this the same as here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32273925/javafx-table-cell-flashing-and-change-cells-text-color ?

Comment: this is talking about TableCell not tableRow

Comment: Which is essentially the same. Just `TableCell` instead of `TableRow` and `cellFactory` instead of `rowFactory`.

Comment: Actually, that's exactly what I did. But I am getting errors and I don't know how to resolve them. This is why I am posting. Please see updates.

Comment: Hi, @eckig, I tried two different methods to solve the problem but still in vain. I saw from other posts that the `getTableRow().getItem()` is used to retrieve the TableRow Object. But this does not work in my code and I cannot figure out why.

Comment: I don't understand why you are trying to do this in a `cellFactory` instead of in a `rowFactory`.

Comment: How would your approach using rowFactory be ? Why would you suggest rowFactory over cellFactory ?Would love to see how your approach would be. Do you mind showing me your approach ? (If possible, can you avoid using lambda expressions cos I find it very diffcult the code sometimes ? )

Comment: Sorry, missed that you only wanted to make one cell flash.

Comment: @James_D So, setRowFactory will not be able to achieve what I want to do here ?

Comment: I think I have answered this [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32310912/javafx-how-do-i-reference-a-particular-cell-within-a-row-in-setrowfactory). Isn't that basically asking exactly the same?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an alternative to @eckig's solution (which is perfectly good: this is just a different approach).

Since all you are basically trying to do is change a style, you can set the CSS pseudoclass on the `TableRow` instead of the `TableCell`, and then just use your CSS stylesheet to update the color of the particular cell you are interested in.

The advantage here, perhaps, is that it is quite a bit easier for the `TableRow` to see any property in the `Trade` class than it is for the `TableCell`, and that your `TableCell` remains of the more intuitive type (`TableCell<Trade, Double>`) with its data being the data displayed.

So you would do

```
fxTransactionLog.setRowFactory(tv -> {
    TableRow<Trade> row = new TableRow<>();
    Timeline flasher = new Timeline(

        new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(0.5), e -> 
            row.pseudoClassStateChanged(flashHighlight, true)),

        new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(1.0), e -> 
            row.pseudoClassStateChanged(flashHighlight, false))
    );

    flasher.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);

    ChangeListener<Boolean> cautionListener = (obs, cautionWasSet, cautionIsNowSet) -> {
        if (cautionIsNowSet) {
            flasher.play();
        } else {
            flasher.stop();
            row.pseudoClassStateChanged(flashHighlight, false);
        }
    };

    cell.itemProperty().addListener((obs, oldItem, newItem) -> {
        if (oldItem != null) {
            oldItem.cautionProperty().removeListener(cautionListener);
        }
        if (newItem == null) {
            flasher.stop();
            row.pseudoClassStateChanged(flashHighlight, false);
        } else {
            newItem.cautionProperty().addListener(cautionListener);
            if (newItem.cautionProperty().get()) { //<-- PROBLEM 3
                flasher.play();
            } else {
                flasher.stop();
                row.pseudoClassStateChanged(flashHighlight, false);
            }
        }
    });
    return row ;
});
```

Now you just need to give the cells you want to react to the change in state a style class. You can do this with the cell factory:

```
fxTransactionLogVolume.setCellFactory(col -> {
    TableCell<Trade, Double> cell = new TableCell<Trade, Double>() {
        @Override
        public void updateItem(Double volume, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(volume, empty);
            if (empty) {
                setText(null);
            } else {
                setText(volume.toString());
            }
        }
    };

    cell.getStyleClass().add("trade-volume-cell");
    return cell ;
}
```

Now in your external stylesheet you can do

```
.table-row-cell:flash-highlight .trade-volume-cell {
    -fx-background-color: transparent, green ;
    -fx-text-fill: yellow ;
}
```

Note that you can use any cell implementation you like here; since the "flashing" is really controlled by the table row, it doesn't interfere. So if you have some more sophisticated cell implementation (e.g. with editing), you can still use it:

```
fxTransactionLogVolume.setCellFactory( col -> {
    MySpecialTableCell cell = new MySpecialTableCell();
    cell.getStyleClass().add("trade-volume-cell");
    return cell ;
});
```

with

```
public class MySpecialTableCell extends TableCell<Trade, Double> {

    // whatever you need to do here...

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Ah okay, now I understand your problem.. for starters the `TableView<T>`:

- Is typed (`T`) to display a specific kind of Object, in your case `Trade`
- The concrete instances are held in the [`TableView`s items](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TableView.html#getItems--). The visual items are grouped into `TableRows` of this type `T` (here `Trade`)
- Each `TableCell<T,V>` (one for each `TableColumn<T,V>`) per `TableRow` is meant to display a single attribute of `T`, e.g. `Double`. Thus the `TableCell` is typed to `TableCell<T,Double>`.

The solution for your problem usually is to not use an attribute of `T` for the `TableCell` but the item itself, so `TableCell<T,T>` or in your case `TableCell<Trade,Trade>`.

The adapted `AnimatedTableCell` would then look like this:

```
public static class AnimatedTableCell<T> extends TableCell<T,T>{
    private static final PseudoClass PS_Cell_Flash = PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("flash-cell-positive");

    private final Function<T,BooleanExpression> flashExtractor;
    private final ChangeListener<Boolean> flashListener = (fObs, fOld, fNew) -> flasherChanged(fNew);
    private final Timeline flashTimeline;

    // constructor
    public AnimatedTableCell(Function<T, BooleanExpression> fFlashExtractor){
        flashExtractor = fFlashExtractor;
        flashTimeline = new Timeline(
                new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(0.5), e -> pseudoClassStateChanged(PS_Cell_Flash, true)),
                new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(1.0), e -> pseudoClassStateChanged(PS_Cell_Flash, false)));
        flashTimeline.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);
    }

    private void flasherChanged(boolean fNew) {
        if (fNew) {
            flashTimeline.play();
        } else {
            flashTimeline.stop();
            pseudoClassStateChanged(PS_Cell_Flash, false);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void updateItem(T item, boolean empty) {
        if (getItem() != null) {
            // Problem IN THIS LINE
            final BooleanExpression be = flashExtractor.apply(getItem());
            if (be != null) {
                be.removeListener(flashListener);
            }
        }

        super.updateItem(item, empty);

        if (getItem() != null) {
            final BooleanExpression be = flashExtractor.apply(getItem());
            if (be != null) {
                be.addListener(flashListener);
                flasherChanged(be.get());
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: @mynameisJEFF You need to adjust the type of your `TableColumn` too.. e.g. `TableColumn<Trade,Trade>`.

Comment: In that case, how would I be able to display the `VolumeProperty` on this particular column ? Can you give me an example please ? I think I kind of understand what you are saying. But I think an example will make things a lot clearer to me.

Comment: In your `TableCell` `getItem()` now returns the `Trade` object. You can access it like any other java object.. e.g. `getItem().getXyz()`.

Comment: Would I be able to edit the `Volume` (the double value in the same cell that now has the ability to flash  ) in this case?

Comment: You can call setters too.. all basic Java ;-)