# Javafx: how do I reference a particular cell within a row in setRowFactory?

Tags: java, javafx

I have a tableView, where each table row represents an object and each column represents the attributes of the object. Within the tableView, I am defining a `setRowFactory`.

Within the `setRowFactory`, I want to be able to have access to a particular cell within the row  and highlight it by doing this: `ThisCellofThisRow.pseudoClassStateChanged(...)`

**Problem is:** I have no idea how to reference this `ThisCellofThisRow`.

Comment: Who changes the pseudo class state of the column? Maybe you can ask this component for the state of your row?

Comment: what do you mean who ? I just want to know how to call / refer to a particular cell box within a row and highlight that cell that cell box. The call / reference part is the part I fail to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure exactly what you want to do, but you could change the pseudoclass state of the row, and then use CSS to select the particular column. That way the row factory doesn't have to access the cell at all.

Example:

highlight-cell-in-row.css:

```
/*
** Gives a yellow background to a table cell with style class "value-cell"
** that is inside a row with the "high" psuedoclass set 
*/

.table-row-cell:high .value-cell {
    -fx-background-color: transparent, yellow ;
}
```

TableViewHighlightItem.java:

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.function.Function;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.IntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyBooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyBooleanWrapper;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.css.PseudoClass;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TableCell;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableRow;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class TableViewHighlightItem extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        // create table and columns:
        TableView<Item> table = new TableView<>();
        TableColumn<Item, String> nameCol = column("Name", Item::nameProperty);
        TableColumn<Item, Number> valueCol = column("Value", Item::valueProperty);
        table.getColumns().add(nameCol);
        table.getColumns().add(valueCol);

        // basic default cell, but with "value-cell" always added as a CSS class:
        valueCol.setCellFactory(col -> {
            TableCell<Item, Number> cell = new TableCell<Item, Number>(){
                @Override
                public void updateItem(Number value, boolean empty) {
                    super.updateItem(value, empty);
                    if (empty) {
                        setText(null);
                    } else {
                        setText(value.toString());
                    }
                }
            };
            cell.getStyleClass().add("value-cell");
            return cell ;
        });

        PseudoClass high = PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("high");

        // Table row toggles "high" pseudoclass according to state of current item in row:
        table.setRowFactory(tv -> {
            TableRow<Item> row = new TableRow<>();

            ChangeListener<Boolean> highListener = (obs, wasHigh, isNowHigh) -> 
                row.pseudoClassStateChanged(high, isNowHigh);

            row.itemProperty().addListener((obs, oldItem, newItem) -> {
                if (oldItem != null) {
                    oldItem.highProperty().removeListener(highListener);
                }
                if (newItem == null) {
                    row.pseudoClassStateChanged(high, false);
                } else {
                    row.pseudoClassStateChanged(high, newItem.isHigh());
                    newItem.highProperty().addListener(highListener);
                }
            });

            return row ;
        });

        Random rng = new Random();

        // Button to test changing data to random values:
        Button changeButton = new Button("Change Data");
        changeButton.setOnAction(e -> 
                table.getItems().forEach(item -> item.setValue(rng.nextInt(20))));

        // add data to table:
        for (int i = 1 ; i <= 40 ; i++) {
            table.getItems().add(new Item("Item "+i, rng.nextInt(20)));
        }

        // layout:
        BorderPane root = new BorderPane(table, null, null, changeButton, null);
        BorderPane.setAlignment(changeButton, Pos.CENTER);
        BorderPane.setMargin(changeButton, new Insets(10));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 600, 600);
        scene.getStylesheets().add("highlight-cell-in-row.css");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    // utility method for creating columns:
    private static <S,T> TableColumn<S,T> column(String title, Function<S, ObservableValue<T>> property) {
        TableColumn<S,T> column = new TableColumn<>(title);
        column.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> property.apply(cellData.getValue()));
        return column ;
    }

    // model class:
    public static class Item {
        private final StringProperty name = new SimpleStringProperty();
        private final IntegerProperty value = new SimpleIntegerProperty();
        private final ReadOnlyBooleanWrapper high = new ReadOnlyBooleanWrapper();

        public Item(String name, int value) {
            setName(name);
            setValue(value);
            high.bind(this.value.greaterThanOrEqualTo(10));
        }

        public final StringProperty nameProperty() {
            return this.name;
        }

        public final String getName() {
            return this.nameProperty().get();
        }

        public final void setName(final String name) {
            this.nameProperty().set(name);
        }

        public final IntegerProperty valueProperty() {
            return this.value;
        }

        public final int getValue() {
            return this.valueProperty().get();
        }

        public final void setValue(final int value) {
            this.valueProperty().set(value);
        }

        public final ReadOnlyBooleanProperty highProperty() {
            return this.high.getReadOnlyProperty();
        }

        public final boolean isHigh() {
            return this.highProperty().get();
        }


    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @James_D, really appreciated your answer, does your code make the cell flash or the row flash ? My ultimate goal is to make a cell flash , not the entire row flash

Comment: Why don't you run it and see? It highlights just the cell, because the CSS applies the color just to the cell. You can use code from your previous question to add "flashing" functionality.

Comment: So the key here is `.value-cell` and  assign CSS class to the desired cell using this: `cell.getStyleClass().add("value-cell");` ? In this sense, the cell has a  `value-cell` tag and this is how it is linked with the css file ? In fact, I dont have to use `.value-cell`, I can call it `.something` and reference it probably, am i correct ?

Comment: Yes, it is just a CSS class name. You can obviously use any name you want, ideally you should make something that is logically sensible within the context of your application.